# Python AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'youtube'

Tags: python

I get this error  `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'youtube'` but there is a database column returned called `youtube`

```
@app.route('/watch-movie/<slug>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def watch_movie(slug):
    connection = mysql.get_db()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM videos WHERE slug=%s AND published=1',(slug))
    data = cursor.fetchall()


    youtube = data[0].youtube 
    embed = youtube.replace("watch?v=", "embed/")


    return render_template('watch_movie.html',data=data,embed=embed)
```

How do i solve?

Comment: Perhaps `data[0]['youtube']` is what you want?

Comment: thanks.  How come within the template `watch_movie.html`  i do `{{data[0].youtube}}` and i get a result but not here?

Comment: That's probably because the template file is written in Jinja2, not python. So differences are to be expected.